# AppleScript Error - Can’t get group 1 of window "Control Center"

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, bluetooth, monterey

## Expected

Run an AppleScript in order to toggle the Mac's Bluetooth on/off.

## Actual

**Error**

> The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “System Events got an error: Can’t get group 1 of window "Control Center" of process "ControlCenter". Invalid index.”

## Script

This script has worked on previous macOS versions as outlined in the post [AppleScript to toggle Bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68268794/2253682).

*Bluetooth Toggle.workflow*

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "ControlCenter"
        set BluetoothButton to menu bar item "Bluetooth" of menu bar 1
        click BluetoothButton
        delay 1
        set OnSwitch to checkbox "Bluetooth" of group 1 of window "Control Center"
        click OnSwitch
    end tell
    key code 53
end tell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Monterey** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>
- Requires the **[√] Show in Menu Bar** *checkbox* to be checked in: **System Preferences** > **Dock & Menu Bar** > **Bluetooth**

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Control Center"
        click menu bar item "Bluetooth" of menu bar 1
        tell window "Control Center"
            try
                click checkbox "Bluetooth"
            on error
                click checkbox "Bluetooth"
            end try
        end tell
    end tell
    key code 53 -- # escape key
end tell
```

**Notes:**

**Apple** continues with each release of **macOS** to cripple **AppleScript** and as such I had to use some *error handling* to trap the error and click the **Bluetooth** *checkbox* twice in order for it to work.

As noted in the opening of my answer, how this was tested and does indeed work for me under the conditions stated. YMMV

If you do not want to have the **Bluetooth** *menu* on the **menu bar** separate from the **Control Center**, you can use the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

- The **[] Show in Menu Bar** *checkbox* is not checked in: **System Preferences** > **Dock & Menu Bar** > **Bluetooth**

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Control Center"
        click menu bar item "Control Center" of menu bar 1
        click checkbox "Bluetooth" of window "Control Center"
    end tell
    key code 53 -- # escape key
end tell
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: The first AppleScript example above works well for my use case on the 2019  Macbook Pro running macOS Monterey Version 12.0.1. Thank you for solving @user3439894!

Comment: It seems that it stopped working on Monterey 12.4:

System Events got an error: Can’t get window "Control Center" of application process "ControlCenter".

Answer (score 0):

This following solution requires [Homebrew - The Missing Package Manager for macOS (or Linux)](https://brew.sh/) to be installed on your system.

In **Terminal.app**, the command line tool - **[blueutil](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/blueutil#default)**, can be installed with this command: `brew install blueutil`

After successful installation of **Homebrew** then **blueutil**, the **blueutil** can be used in your **AppleScript**

```
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/blueutil -p toggle"
```

- Does Not Require the **[√] Show in Menu Bar** *checkbox* to be checked in: **System Preferences** > **Dock & Menu Bar** > **Bluetooth**